# What's the usage of field's SQLDataType in JOOQ's auto generated classes

Tags: jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

When generating JOOQ classes via JOOQ code gen, for each field, there will be a SQLDataType associated with it like below.

```
public final TableField<EventsRecord, LocalDateTime> CREATED_AT = createField(DSL.name("CREATED_AT"), SQLDataType.LOCALDATETIME(6).nullable(false), this, "");
```

What's the usage or purpose to have SQLDataType with each generated field? Since we already have a return type and client code is likely to use the this type to do the compile check.

Why we still need to know the actual SQLDataType in generated class/fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By client type, you probably mean the `LocalDateTime` type, i.e. the `<T>` type that you will find throughout the jOOQ API. Sure, that's the type *you* care about, but jOOQ, internally, will care about the `org.jooq.DataType` instead. Your example already gives away two ideas why this may be useful:

- There's a precision of 6 fractional digits on `LOCALDATETIME(6)`, which is used (among other things):

  - In [`CAST` expressions](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/cast-expressions/). Try `DSL.cast(inline("2000-01-01 00:00:00"), EVENTS.CREATED_AT)`,
  - In [DDL statements](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/ddl-statements/). Try [`DSLContext.meta(EVENTS)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#meta(org.jooq.Table...)). You should see a `CREATE TABLE` statement with the appropriate data type
  - In the optimistic locking feature, to create modification timestamps with the right precision.
- There's an indication whether the column is nullable, which is used (again among other things):

  - In DDL statements, see above
  - In the [implicit join feature](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-join/), to decide whether to produce an `INNER JOIN` or a `LEFT JOIN`
- There are many other properties a `DataType` can have, which would be interesting for jOOQ at runtime including:

  - Custom data type bindings
  - Character set
  - Collation
  - Converters
  - Default value
  - Whether it is an identity
- Besides, a `String` is not a `String`. For example, it could mean `CHAR(2)`, `CHAR(5)`, `VARCHAR(100)`, `CLOB`, which are all quite different things in some dialects.

It would be a shame if your runtime meta model didn't have this information available.